# RabbitMQ With With Docker Compose rabbitmq.config file gets replaced on Run

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose, dockerfile

i have tried this a number of times and every time i run `docker-compose up` my rabbitmq.config file gets replaced.

The following is my dockerfile.

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.6.11-managment
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
RUN rabbitmq-plugins list
COPY  ./config/rabbitmq.config ../../etc/rabbitmq/ 
COPY  ./config/test.json ../../etc/rabbitmq/
```

and this is my Docker-Compose File.

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbit:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: rabbit.dockerfile
    container_name: rabbit
    hostname: lightrabbit    
    networks:
      - rabnet
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=abcd
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=pass    
    volumes:
      - ./config/rabbitmq:/etc/rabbitmq:rw
      - ./data:/var/lib/rabbitmq:rw
      - ./logs:/var/log/rabbitmq:rw
    ports:
      - 15672:15672  
      - 5672:5672
volumes:
  rabbitdata:
    driver: local
networks:
    rabnet:
        driver: bridge
```

I even added a volume mapping to the folder to test it.
The Reasons i am running `RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management` in my dockerfile is because management plugin is not enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

Changed my docker file to this

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.6.11-management
COPY rabbitmq.config /etc/rabbitmq/
RUN chmod 777 /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
WORKDIR /var/lib/rabbitmq/
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management  --offline
RUN rabbitmq-plugins list
```

and my compose file to this

```
version: '2'
services:
  rabbit:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: rabbit.dockerfile
    container_name: rabbit
    hostname: lightrabbit    
    networks:
      - rabnet
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=lighttrading
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=P@ssw0rd_rabbit                 
    ports:
      - 15672:15672  
      - 5672:5672    

volumes:
  rabbitdata:
    driver: local
networks:
    rabnet:
        driver: bridge
```

**One of the tricky parts is its a must to define this section inside our rabbitmq.config other wise running the command  `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management` will not work**

```
{ rabbitmq_management, [
        { listener, [
            { port, 15672 },
            { ssl, false }
        ] },
        { load_definitions, "/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json" }
    ] }
```